# How to check if the number sequence does NOT converge?

Tags: algorithm, numbers, sequence

This is a job interview question:

Given a positive integer n, you can generate a sequence of numbers with this function:

```
f(n) = n/2 if n is even
f(n) = 3*n+1 if n is odd
```

So for n=3, the sequence is:

```
3 10 5 16 8 4 2 1
```

If you try a few positive numbers, the sequence always converges to 1.

**Now write a program to check if every number between 2-N (a very large integer) will converge to 1.**

My guess is that: if the sequence doesn't converge, it may very likely enter a loop like this:

```
...,k,3k+1,...,k,...
```

It is easy to check if a number has been generated before. My interviewer asks: **what if the sequence never converges and never enters a loop? How do you check for that?**

If I don't detect such a condition, it will result in a stack overflow, as I am using a recursive function to solve this problem.

If it never enters a loop, how can I be sure that it will not eventually converge? Say after a few iterations of odd/even/odd/even, the numbers keep getting larger, but what if some 3*N+1 happens to be a power of two, and it directly converges to 1?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just to clarify, the sequence is generated by repeatedly applying the function to the previous result.

Comment: You can avoid using recursive functions (or use tail recursion, which can be trivially unrolled into a loop), but the problem is that a non-cyclic case would have to be an infinite series with no repeated number, so you'd have to call the function an infinite times to be sure that is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sequence is the well-known `3n+1` sequence for which there is the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture). This is still an open problem because the question is extremely hard.

> What if the sequence never converges and never enters a loop? How do you check for that?

The behavior of this sequence is not known. The only way to check this is to prove it. Sadly, there is still no proof. So what you could is to hope that it would converge to 1 (there is still no couterexample found).

So your program should be something like: you start iterating over the sequence and saving all found values in a set. If you've found the same value twice you stop and say that there is a counterexample. If for all values your program stop and you get to `1` you've proven that all values in the range `2-N` converge to `1`. If your program doesn't stop you can't say anything.

> Any counterexample to the Collatz conjecture would have to consist
>   either of an infinite divergent trajectory or a cycle different from
>   the trivial (4; 2; 1) cycle.